# C# Trigger a function in a class by its name

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net-core

I am trying to write code to check for requirements for a student before being allowed to register for classes. I want this requirements check to be dynamic, in case requirements change, or might need to add new requirements and only do the checks if this requirement is activated (maybe not all students need that requirement).

I created an interface with the types of requirements:

```
public interface IBasicRequirementsEvaluator
    {
        RequirementResult CheckForFiles();

        RequirementResult CheckForFinancialHold();

        RequirementResult CheckForRegistrationHold();

        RequirementResult CheckForStandingID();

        RequirementResult CheckForGraduationDate();
    }
```

and then their implementations:

```
public class BasicChecksImplementations : IBasicRequirementsEvaluator
    {
        private StudentData _data { get; set; }

        public BasicChecksImplementations(StudentData data)
        {
            data = _data;
        }


        public RequirementResult CheckForFiles()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public RequirementResult CheckForFinancialHold()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public RequirementResult CheckForGraduationDate()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public RequirementResult CheckForRegistrationHold()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public RequirementResult CheckForStandingID()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

and then trying to perform checks only if the check is activated, by having the name of the requirement check present in a collection of strings:

```
public RequirementsResult CheckBasicRequirements (StudentData data, List<string> CheckActionNamesList)
        {
            RequirementsResult result = new RequirementsResult();
            BasicChecksImplementations checks = new BasicChecksImplementations(data);

            var methods = checks.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public);

            foreach (string actionName in CheckActionNamesList)
            {
                var method = methods.Where(x => x.Name == actionName).FirstOrDefault();
                method.Invoke(this, null);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

But there is nothing in the variable methods, so obviously this is wrong. (also is there a design pattern that I could use to achieve this?).

Comment: It seems like maybe a good case for the [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern to me.

Comment: You should include BindingFlags.Instance in the search

Comment: @codein what does that do?

Comment: It will search for all public and instance methods in the type. so use GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)

Comment: thanks @codein appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar to a Strategy Pattern could work. I don't know how you need to handle the results so I've simplified them in my example.

First, we create an interface that each evaluator will implement to perform the evaluation, `IRequirementEvaluator`. We also create another interface for the return result, `IRequirementResult`.

```
public interface IRequirementEvaluator
{
    IRequirementResult Evaluate();
}

public interface IRequirementResult
{
    bool IsValid { get; }
    string Message { get; }
}
```

Next, we create each evaluator object and implement the `IRequirementEvaluator` interface in each one. Note, since each evaluator is contained in its own class, you could easily implement a new evaluator without touching any of the existing evaluator code.

```
public class CheckForFiles : IRequirementEvaluator
{
    private string inputValue;
    public CheckForFiles(string inputValue)
    {
        // pass params to ctor and use them in evaluate method
        this.inputValue = inputValue;
    }

    public IRequirementResult Evaluate()
    {
        // used ctor params to evaluate
        bool isValid = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputValue);
        return new RequirementResult(false, $"Evaluation on {this.GetType().Name} {(isValid ? "was Successful" : "has Failed")}.");
    }
}

public class CheckForFinancialHold : IRequirementEvaluator
{
    private readonly decimal amountDue = 0m;
    public CheckForFinancialHold(decimal amountDue)
    {
    // pass params to ctor and use them in evaluate method
    this.amountDue = amountDue;
    }

    public IRequirementResult Evaluate()
    {
        // used ctor params to evaluate
        bool isValid = amountDue <= 0m;
        return new RequirementResult(false, $"Evaluation on {this.GetType().Name} {(isValid ? "was Successful" : "has Failed")}.");
    }
}

public class CheckForRegistrationHold : IRequirementEvaluator
{
    public CheckForRegistrationHold()
    {
        // pass params to ctor and use them in evaluate method
    }

    public IRequirementResult Evaluate()
    {
        // used ctor params to evaluate
        bool isValid = false;
    return new RequirementResult(false, $"Evaluation on {this.GetType().Name} {(isValid ? "was Successful" : "has Failed")}.");
    }
}

public class CheckForStandingId : IRequirementEvaluator
{
    public CheckForStandingId()
    {
        // pass params to ctor and use them in evaluate method
    }

    public IRequirementResult Evaluate()
    {
        // used ctor params to evaluate
        bool isValid = false;
    return new RequirementResult(false, $"Evaluation on {this.GetType().Name} {(isValid ? "was Successful" : "has Failed")}.");
    }
}

public class CheckForGraduationDate : IRequirementEvaluator
{
    public CheckForGraduationDate()
    {
        // pass params to ctor and use them in evaluate method
    }

    public IRequirementResult Evaluate()
    {
        // used ctor params to evaluate
        bool isValid = false;
        return new RequirementResult(false, $"Evaluation on {this.GetType().Name} {(isValid ? "was Successful" : "has Failed")}.");
    }
}
```

Finally, we implement the `BasicChecksEvaluator`, which also implements the `IRequirementEvaluator` interface. This object will require a list of evaluators to be passed in its constructor. This list will be iterated and each `Evaluate` method called in turn when the `BasicChecksEvaluator`s `Evaluate` method is called.

```
public class BasicChecksEvaluator : IRequirementEvaluator
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IRequirementEvaluator> evaluators;

    public BasicChecksEvaluator(IList<IRequirementEvaluator> evaluators)
    {
        if (evaluators == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(evaluators));
        if(!evaluators.Any()) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(evaluators));
        this.evaluators = evaluators;
    }

    public IRequirementResult Evaluate()
    {
        IList<IRequirementResult> results = new List<IRequirementResult>();
        bool isValid = true;
        foreach (var e in evaluators)
        {
            var result = e.Evaluate();
            // if one evaluator is invalid then the final result is invalid
            isValid = isValid && result.IsValid;
            results.Add(result);
        }
        // return final isValid result along with all messages concatenated
        return new RequirementResult(isValid, string.Join(Environment.NewLine, results.Select(r => r.Message).ToArray()));
    }
}
```

To use this in your application, you create a list of `IRequirementEvaluator`s and pass them to the `BasicChecksEvaluator`s constructor. You could easily select the evaluators you want to include or exclude.

```
IList<IRequirementEvaluator> evaluators = new List<IRequirementEvaluator>();
evaluators.Add(new CheckForFiles("some param value that's being passed in"));
evaluators.Add(new CheckForGraduationDate());
evaluators.Add(new CheckForFinancialHold(0m));
// evaluators.Add(new CheckForRegistrationHold()); // <-- commented out to exclude 
evaluators.Add(new CheckForStandingId());
BasicChecksEvaluator bce = new BasicChecksEvaluator(evaluators);
var result = bce.Evaluate();

// which outputs the following...

// IsValid is False
// Evaluation on CheckForFiles was Successful.
// Evaluation on CheckForGraduationDate has Failed. <--- caused evaluation to fail
// Evaluation on CheckForFinancialHold was Successful.
// Evaluation on CheckForStandingId has Failed. <--- caused evaluation to fail
```

Additionally, the usage example above could be encapsulated in objects and allow you do something like below, where you could hide the details as to which evaluators are called in the different scenarios.

```
public class NewStudentEvaluator { // new student logic }
public class ReturningStudentEvaluator { // returning student logic }
```